# Can we please close this offensive question?

Tags: discussion, on-topic-off-topic, offensive

The author of [this  post](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/549115/extremism-what-s-the-cultural-history-of-this-word) has suggested that *autism* and *mutism*  are ***defects***.

> “Extremism” sounds like an ideology, by analogy with Marxism for example; or possibly it’s more akin to a behavioural state like ***mutism or autism*** - a kind of **pathology or defect.**

Might I remind the rest of the community that this is offensive to many of us. In fact, [Greta Thunberg has said that ASD is her "super power"](https://www.theguardian.com/environment/2019/sep/02/greta-thunberg-responds-to-aspergers-critics-its-a-superpower).

The OP has been warned by none other  than diamond star user (Mod)   Andrew Leach that the question **must** be edited.

> I concur with Cascabel. While I hesitate at the 100-rep penalty, you **must** edit this question.

So far, that has not happened. Can we please edit, or close / delete this post?

Comment: Cascabel, can you suggest alternate wording? What are words that are acceptable to describe 'mutism' or 'autism' (separately and together)? Are those words themselves objectionable and can you suggest replacements?

Comment: Why exactly is *defect* so much worse than *disorder* In this context? Going by the dictionary definitions they seem to be pretty close in meaning, so whatever subtle difference in the implications there may be between them, it cannot be assumed that it would be obvious to everyone.

Comment: @jsw29 _Disorder_ is the "accepted"
  terminology. What do you do with a defective machine? It's bad, so you either junk it, or repair it. Autism cannot be "fixed", any more than homosexuality. _That_ is why it is offensive. Just because it is not obvious to everybody is no excuse. Not long ago we had quite a controversy over LGBTQ pronouns; before that not many were aware of the differences...

Comment: [cont] A _defect_ is "a shortcoming, imperfection, or lack." A _disorder_ is a "is a functional abnormality or disturbance".  _Abnormal_  only means that it falls outside of the statistical range. Equating the two is unfair.

Comment: Yes, I would not call a pathology _a defect_. It seems also to imply that the person soffering is _defective_. If there is any word that is offensive toward a group of people, that can be edited by any user. It's when the OP keeps re-adding that word that is required a moderator's action.

Comment: Parasitism isn't a disease, it's a way of existence/sustenance, one organism feeding off another, which is sometimes harmful, and sometimes goes completely unnoticed. As you have wandered into medical territory advancing misinformation, *I'm* a bit offended. See how unknowingly people give offense and how easily offense is taken? Please delete this question. Or at least edit it to reflect reality. (Medically speaking, is *hemophilia* a disease? A disorder? A "condition"? It's certainly *atypical*. )

Comment: @kiamlaluno - What if a defective enzyme causes autism? Defective enzymes cause many disorders, a lot of them so disordered that embryos die *in utero*. Should we describe the protein as *alternatately functioning*?

Comment: @Cascabel - Btw, my request was purposely overly dramatic, although I sincerely do dislike medical or scientific misinformation.

Comment: @anongoodnurse I am speaking of pathology as "defect" of a person. That doesn't mean _defective_ cannot be used.

Comment: @Cascabel - I *am* a doctor, and "parasitism" is not a disease, no matter what the encyclopedia says. There are parasitic *diseases*, e.g. schistosomiasis. But is it a disease, a condition, or just atypical? Brouhaha? You're missing the point. I was imitating your words, tone, and dramatic reaction. Look to yourself, Cascabel. Again, though, I sincerely do dislike medical or scientific misinformation.

Comment: @anongoodnurse It is generally agreed here (including among the moderators) that calling autism a _defect_ is exclusionary language. As Matt E. Эллен♦ said, "They should not refer to autism or mutism as defects. It's rude and exclusionary language." Why do you take offense with that? And now you say  that you are mocking me. Look to your own reaction. I'm done with this. Do not reply.

Comment: @Cascabel - You may be done with this, but that doesn't control my actions. I also challenged Matt's answer. You really are missing the point entirely. And trust me on *parasitism*; I'm a doctor. I even practiced for a couple of months in Africa, where *parasitic diseases* (or illnesses, e.g. malaria) are absolutely rampant!

Comment: @anongoodnurse How do your numerous and excessive comments about  parasites invalidate my post on exclusionary language towards autistic people?  I deleted the "offending" comment, so you no  longer have anything to complain about.

Comment: I suggest that you take a look at this article: [Many autistic scholars and self-advocates view autism as a form of diversity rather than pathology, and an increasing number of researchers similarly conceptualize autism in terms of strengths and weaknesses rather than only deficits](https://www.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/pmc/articles/PMC5368186/) The question was intended to raise awareness..for some reason there is much resistance to the idea here...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I have deleted it until the content is changed.

Comment: What is meant by changing its "content"? Is the question on topic (ignoring the OP's definition of autism and mutism as defects) or not? If the author of the question replaced the term *defect* with say, *condition* or *disorder*, would that make it acceptable? Does the author have to remove them? What exactly does the author have to change?

Comment: They should not refer to autism or mutism as defects. It's rude and exclusionary language. Once that is changed I (or someone else if they feel happy to) will undelete the question. It's on topic nature is not why it has been deleted

Comment: Thank you, it is good to hear that the question is on topic. Would replacing "defects" with "disorders" or "condition” be more respectful?  Should the OP (or editor) also remove "pathology"? Should the two terms, mutism and autism,  be replaced?

Comment: Maybe  replacing the offensive terms (defects and pathology) with *negative connotations* would not only be an improvement but would help clarify the question.

Comment: @Mari-LouA "_Negative connotations_" of autism / "mutism" an improvement? Really?

Comment: @Cascabel Sometimes, we have to assume good faith, is that fair. I have suggested other solutions, please tell me which you think are more acceptable?

Comment: Please see my comments under the OP @Mari-LouA Right now I am writing an answer to my own Q.

Comment: Replaced with 'disorder'. Though the question is in earnest, a social history of the word seems 1) just plain off topic according to our usual practice (but I could be convinced that we should allow such things as on-topic) 2) asking for too much exposition (but I could be convinced that exposition on social subjects should be allowed as on-topic.)

Comment: OP edited to remove the offense. Please undelete.

Comment: @Mitch I'm not sure it has removed the offence; even the word *disorder* is loaded. And in any case, the question is off-topic.

Comment: @AndrewLeach 1) I changed it to a word that was acceptable to the OP on this meta question. Specifically, autism also goes by the term 'autistic spectrum disorder'. While the latter may be loaded or objectionable to you it is pretty standard. 2) I think it is questionable that the question is off-topic, so I think we should go through the usual procedure of close voting to check that.

Comment: I've repositioned the term "disorder", now matched more closely with "extremism", and I've removed the OP's request about its equivalent in other languages.

Comment: @Mitch sorry, I didn't realise you commented only an hour ago. I saw the edit was several hours old and  I jumped in. Feel free to rollback the edit if you believe it's too "extreme".

Comment: @Mari-LouA I had trouble parsing the latest (what is modified by what is unclear). I don't find it extreme, just needs rearranging. The addition of lexico is fine though. Let me try another edit and see if that is what you were thinking (I'm trying to keep as much of the original as possible but changing the offending part).

Comment: *Happy to undelete once the content is changed to not refer to autism or mutism as defects.* What else needs to be done?

Comment: Is all this worth it?

Comment: @Mitch HI! Sorry, I wasn't online for a bit. I'll undelete it

Comment: @MattE.Эллен Yay! Now it'll probably be closed.

Comment: @Cascabel I removed what I think is any kind of offense entirely. It may still be an underspecified question and very closable, but I thought I'd try to make it available to anybody who could tackle it. It's not as much about the single word 'extremism' but about the meaning of '-ism' as a suffix.

Comment: @Mitch Something that disturbs me...my post here has garnered 2 DVs....that seems to indicate that the topic of "exclusionism" seems off-topic to some people when it is about autistic or mute people. LGBTQ gets all the attention while people like us fall through the cracks. It should be obvious, but it isn't. That ain't fair.

Comment: @Cascabel Who knows what down- (or up-) voters are really thinking (there were also 3 upvotes here). Maybe they just disagree that it is as big an issue as you (downvoting is much freer on meta) because they just don't see it (it's not as well-represented in the media). Like with any kind of awareness of offense, it doesn't happen to a majority of people so they think it doesn't exist.

Comment: @MattE.Эллен - Good grief! Is *neuroatypical* also rude and exclusionary? I can see how someone who is neuroatypical could be offended by that

Comment: @anongoodnurse i don't know. In this context *defect* is, as people in the group being labelled such have said so. I'm afraid, unless I already know, I can only react as things are brought to light.